# RST/Sphinx create inline target markup inside array

Tags: python-sphinx, restructuredtext

I have an array in sphinx / rst, and I would like to reference a line or cell from other part of my documentation.

How can I create an inline markup reference target in the array?

The array looks like this:

```
+-----------------+-------------------------+-------------------------------------------------------+
| e               | c                       | p                                                     |
+=================+=========================+=======================================================+
| e1              | c1                      | p1                                                    |
+-----------------+-------------------------+-------------------------------------------------------+
| e2              | c2                      | p2                                                    |
+-----------------+-------------------------+-------------------------------------------------------+
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did not think this was possible, but this worked for me.

```
  +----+----+-------------------------+
  | e  | c  | .. _my-reference-label: |
  |    |    |                         |
  |    |    | p                       |
  +====+====+=========================+
  | e1 | c1 | p1                      |
  +----+----+-------------------------+
  | e2 | c2 | p2                      |
  +----+----+-------------------------+
```

and then the link to the target would be:

```
  :ref:`Link title <my-reference-label>`.
```

The formatting makes the targeted cell larger than it should be, but you can fiddle with the other column widths to get percentage widths close enough.